# Chrome Extension - Canceling $interval on navigation

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a AngularJS app implemented in a Chrome Extension. It's using Content Scripts to inject itself into the user's pages as they navigate. In it there's an $interval that calls back to our servers every N seconds as a polling mechanism to check for new data to return to the client.

```
myInterval = $interval(function() {
    // calls back to server
}, 30000);

$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    if (angular.isDefined(myInterval)) {
        $interval.cancel(myInterval);
        myInterval = undefined;
    }
};
```

I noticed the traffic on our servers was increasing so I investigated and found that the query triggered by this interval is slamming our servers at a way higher rate than our users could possibly be triggering under expected conditions. For example, at a rate of 200+ requests per minute from the same user.

It seems the interval is staying alive even after navigating to a new page, closing the tab, etc. I've come to understand that listening for $destroy and canceling the interval takes care of routing changes within the app, but how do I make sure the interval is cancelled when a user undergoes normal browsing activity (since a new interval is about to be created when the next page is loaded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen for what you refer to ad "normal browsing activities", you can register a listener for `window`'s **onbeforeunload** event.

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    $interval.cancel(myInterval);
};
```

Comment: I tried implementing that and it doesn't seem to be firing. I'm putting in   $window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', function (evt) {
                        [setting cookie here]
   $interval.cancel(myInterval);
  });
... and the cookie is not getting set when I navigate.

Comment: I got it firing like: $window.onbeforeunload = function.... looks like it will work, will continue testing and mark as correct when it checks out. In the meantime any thoughts on how I could kill the existing intervals floating around?

Comment: @AbeHendlish: You are right about `addEventListener` not working for `onbeforeunload`. I have run into this problem again, but I still cannot accept the truth (that it doesn't work :)). I updated my answer. Regarding your existing intervals, I am afraid there is not much you can do. The user's have to either close the browser window or reload the extension (but it depends on the exact code that you use in your content script, so I can't be sure either).

Comment: When using `addEventListener` you shouldn't use "**on**" prefix. `$window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (evt) {}, false);` should work.

Comment: @jarrodek: What you say about `addEventListener()` is true. Nevertheless, for some reason I `beforeunload` doesn't seem to get fired (other events fire normally using `addEventListener()`).